# Compiling older gcc with newer GCC, why did make stop without errors?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, gcc, arm64

**Boring background:** I am attempting to get msp430 toolchain to aarch64 (64bit arm). I have recently moved from Gentoo (constant need to add 32-bit use-flags polluting my portage and then checking if they are still necessary... necessity to add abi_x86_32 manually did put the whole Gentoo to its knees).
After 12 years with Gentoo, I was looking to move to arch, but with my Pi4  I got Manjaro with 64-bit support.

I am trying to port msp430 to aarch64. I have got the msp430-binutils to the package, but gcc makes more problems...

**To the point:** When attempting to compile the TI's latest (patched)gcc-9.3.1.11, The make stops during the compilation but I can't find the actual errors which caused it.
Mine PCKGBUILD :

```
# based on apply-patches.sh from msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-patches by texas instruments
# based on a gcc9 PKGBUILD by group of authors
# package for gcc-9.3.0 for MSP430
# This file is written by complete noob.
# No warranty whatsoever

########################################################################
#     Warning!!!!!                                                     #
#   As the parser of texi file is incapable of unicode (not even utf-8)#
#   this package will not pass make stage if BuildPATH contains non-asci characters

pkgbase=msp430-gcc9
pkgname=msp430-gcc
pkgver=9.3.1.11
pkgrel=1
_islver=0.21
pkgdesc="GNU toolchain for the TI MSP430 processor"
arch=('aarch64')
url="https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP430-GCC-OPENSOURCE"
license=('GPL')
makedepends=( 'wget' 'texinfo' 'ncurses' 'zlib' 'msp430-binutils' 'libmpc' 'doxygen' 'python' 'git')
depends=('elfutils' 'libmpc' 'gcc')
options=(!strip !emptydirs !libtool)


            # as some of the shared files have been removed to prevent conflicts with main gcc they have to be already on a system
configure_args_gdb_common=$(echo --disable-{binutils,gas,ld,gprof,etc} --without-{mpfr,lzma} --with-static-standard-libraries --disable-source-highlight)
configure_args_gdb_nopy="--with-python=no"
configure_args_gdb_py="--with-python=python2.7 --program-prefix=msp430-elf- --program-suffix=-py"configure_args_gcc=$(echo --enable-target-optspace --enable-newlib-nano-formatted-io)


source=( "http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSPGCC/9_3_1_2/export/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full.tar.bz2"
        
        http://isl.gforge.inria.fr/isl-${_islver}.tar.xz
        https://occam.cs.pitt.edu/QmcvDZvdTHadc93Dtn4SJi8gMvezxJVeTLk6pJnE8uy1Pr/5du9jMmZ9WGWsGta7qCfAj8xM7btzP/raw/fs64270.patch
        #c89 c99 
        )

sha1sums=('88cbf70edd38f29a88d0dc9e7544f42708f84835'
          '175111adaa8f6bda81a99ba9e200255a3b8075e2'
          'b5d3c80aa04ceef9310e6a6baf8657a88247f244')

_builddir=build

prepare() {
    cd "${srcdir}/msp430-gcc-${pkgver}-source-full/gcc/"
  # Download sources for gcc prerequisites (gmp, mpfr, mpc, and isl)
  (
    # download_prerequisites requires wget which isn't on macOS
    wget() {
      curl -O "$@"
    }
    source ./contrib/download_prerequisites
  )

  # Create a single source tree for gcc and newlib
  for dir in libgloss newlib; do
    ln -fns ../newlib/$dir $dir
  done
  
  
}



build() {
    cd "${srcdir}/msp430-gcc-${pkgver}-source-full/gcc/"
    export PATH=./:$PWD/../../install/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  ./configure $configure_args_common $configure_args_gcc \
               CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="-Os" \
               --prefix=/usr \
               --infodir=/usr/share/info \
               --mandir=/usr/share/man \
               --disable-libssp \
               --disable-nls \
               --target=msp430 \
               --enable-languages=c,c++ \
               --with-gnu-as \
               --with-gnu-ld \
               --with-as=/usr/bin/msp430-as \
               --with-ld=/usr/bin/msp430-ld \
               --with-pkgversion="mspgcc_${_mspgcc_ver}"
  #CFLAGS="-Os -g0 -s" "${srcdir}/gcc-${pkgver}/configure" \
               
  printf "\n\n###########################################\n Predmake\n####################################x\n "
#pushd build/gcc
  (
  CFLAGS="${CFLAGS/-pipe/} -Wno-error"
  CXXFLAGS="${CXXFLAGS/-pipe/} -Wno-error"
    make #>> ./Vystup
    printf "\n\n###########################################\n Pomake\n####################################x\n "
    make html
    make install install-html DESTDIR=$PWD/../../install
  )
#popd
  
  libtool --finish /usr/libexec/gcc/msp430/9.3.1
}

check() {
  #cd ${srcdir}/binutils-*/${_builddir}

  # do not abort on errors - manually check log files
  make -k -j1 check || true

}

package() {
 cd ${srcdir}/gcc-${pkgver}/${_builddir}
  make DESTDIR=${pkgdir} install

  rm -f  ${pkgdir}/usr/lib/libiberty.a
  rm -rf ${pkgdir}/usr/share/man/man7
  rm -rf ${pkgdir}/usr/share/info

  msg "Stripping debugging symbols from binaries"
  local binary
  find ${pkgdir} -type f 2>/dev/null | while read binary ; do
    case "$(file -biz "$binary")" in
      *compressed-encoding*)      # Skip compressed binarys
        ;;
      *application/x-executable*) # Binaries
        /usr/bin/strip "$binary" >/dev/null 2>&1 ;;
    esac
  done
    "${pkgdir}/usr/share/licenses/${pkgname}/LICENSE"
}

# vim:set sts=2 ts=2 sw=2 et:
```

The error Output:

```
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:519,
                 from ../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:38:
In function ‘strncpy’,
    inlined from ‘dyn_string_insert_cstr’ at ../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:280:3:
/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:106:10: warning: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Wstringop-truncation]
  106 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c: In function ‘dyn_string_insert_cstr’:
../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:272:16: note: length computed here
  272 |   int length = strlen (src);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
configure: WARNING: decimal float is not supported for this target, ignored
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:519,
                 from ../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:38:
In function ‘strncpy’,
    inlined from ‘dyn_string_insert_cstr’ at ../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:280:3:
/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:106:10: warning: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Wstringop-truncation]
  106 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c: In function ‘dyn_string_insert_cstr’:
../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:272:16: note: length computed here
  272 |   int length = strlen (src);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:519,
                 from ../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:38:
In function ‘strncpy’,
    inlined from ‘dyn_string_insert_cstr’ at ../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:280:3:
/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:106:10: warning: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ output truncated before terminating nul copying as many bytes from a string as its length [-Wstringop-truncation]
  106 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c: In function ‘dyn_string_insert_cstr’:
../.././libiberty/dyn-string.c:272:16: note: length computed here
  272 |   int length = strlen (src);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
objcopy: /tmp/ls267314: cannot fill debug link section `x': No such file or directory
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
../.././libcpp/expr.c: In function ‘unsigned int cpp_classify_number(cpp_reader*, const cpp_token*, const char**, location_t)’:
../.././libcpp/expr.c:797:18: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  797 |        0, message);
      |                  ^
../.././libcpp/expr.c:800:39: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  800 |           virtual_location, 0, message);
      |                                       ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [Makefile:224: expr.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../.././libcpp/macro.c: In member function ‘vaopt_state::update_type vaopt_state::update(const cpp_token*)’:
../.././libcpp/macro.c:164:23: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  164 |      vaopt_paste_error);
      |                       ^
../.././libcpp/macro.c:193:24: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  193 |       vaopt_paste_error);
      |                        ^
../.././libcpp/macro.c: In function ‘cpp_macro* create_iso_definition(cpp_reader*)’:
../.././libcpp/macro.c:3385:58: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
 3385 |        cpp_error (pfile, CPP_DL_ERROR, paste_op_error_msg);
      |                                                          ^
../.././libcpp/macro.c:3400:58: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
 3400 |        cpp_error (pfile, CPP_DL_ERROR, paste_op_error_msg);
      |                                                          ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [Makefile:224: macro.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2791: all-build-libcpp] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../.././libcpp/expr.c: In function ‘unsigned int cpp_classify_number(cpp_reader*, const cpp_token*, const char**, location_t)’:
../.././libcpp/expr.c:797:18: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  797 |        0, message);
      |                  ^
../.././libcpp/expr.c:800:39: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  800 |           virtual_location, 0, message);
      |                                       ^
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/libexec/gcc/msp430/9.3.1'
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [Makefile:224: expr.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../.././libcpp/macro.c: In member function ‘vaopt_state::update_type vaopt_state::update(const cpp_token*)’:
../.././libcpp/macro.c:164:23: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  164 |      vaopt_paste_error);
      |                       ^
../.././libcpp/macro.c:193:24: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
  193 |       vaopt_paste_error);
      |                        ^
../.././libcpp/macro.c: In function ‘cpp_macro* create_iso_definition(cpp_reader*)’:
../.././libcpp/macro.c:3385:58: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
 3385 |        cpp_error (pfile, CPP_DL_ERROR, paste_op_error_msg);
      |                                                          ^
../.././libcpp/macro.c:3400:58: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
 3400 |        cpp_error (pfile, CPP_DL_ERROR, paste_op_error_msg);
      |                                                          ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [Makefile:224: macro.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:6965: all-libcpp] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:949: all] Error 2
==> CHYBA: Chyba nastala v build().
    Prebieha rušenie...
```

The last two Lines translate as: Error during build() and Cenceling...

last few make lines:

```
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o directives.o -MT directives.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/directives.Tpo ../.././libcpp/directives.c
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o directives-only.o -MT directives-only.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/directives-only.Tpo ../.././libcpp/directives-only.c
gcc -c -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-overlength-strings -pedantic -Wno-long-long   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.././fixincludes -I../include -I../.././fixincludes/../include ../.././fixincludes/server.c
gcc -c -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-overlength-strings -pedantic -Wno-long-long   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.././fixincludes -I../include -I../.././fixincludes/../include ../.././fixincludes/procopen.c
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o errors.o -MT errors.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/errors.Tpo ../.././libcpp/errors.c
gcc -c -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-overlength-strings -pedantic -Wno-long-long   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.././fixincludes -I../include -I../.././fixincludes/../include ../.././fixincludes/fixlib.c
gcc -c -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wno-overlength-strings -pedantic -Wno-long-long   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.././fixincludes -I../include -I../.././fixincludes/../include ../.././fixincludes/fixopts.c
srcdir="../.././fixincludes" /bin/sh ../.././fixincludes/mkfixinc.sh msp430-unknown-none
sed -e 's/@gcc_version@/9.3.1/' < mkheaders.almost > mkheadersT
mv -f mkheadersT mkheaders
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o expr.o -MT expr.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/expr.Tpo ../.././libcpp/expr.c
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o files.o -MT files.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/files.Tpo ../.././libcpp/files.c
gcc -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -o fixincl fixincl.o fixtests.o fixfixes.o server.o procopen.o fixlib.o fixopts.o ../libiberty/libiberty.a
echo timestamp > full-stamp
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc/host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes'
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o identifiers.o -MT identifiers.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/identifiers.Tpo ../.././libcpp/identifiers.c
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --tag=disable-static  --mode=link gcc -Wall -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -Wc,-static-libgcc  -module -bindir /usr/libexec/gcc/msp430/9.3.1    -Xcompiler '-static-libstdc++' -Xcompiler '-static-libgcc' '-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now' -o liblto_plugin.la -rpath /usr/libexec/gcc/msp430/9.3.1 lto-plugin.lo  -Wc,../libiberty/pic/libiberty.a 
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/lto-plugin.o    -march=armv8-a -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z -Wl,relro -Wl,-z -Wl,now ../libiberty/pic/libiberty.a   -Wl,-soname -Wl,liblto_plugin.so.0 -o .libs/liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "liblto_plugin.so.0" && ln -s "liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0" "liblto_plugin.so.0")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "liblto_plugin.so" && ln -s "liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0" "liblto_plugin.so")
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "liblto_plugin.la" && ln -s "../liblto_plugin.la" "liblto_plugin.la" )
echo "#define LOCALEDIR \"/usr/share/locale\"" > localedir.new
../.././libcpp/../move-if-change localedir.new localedir.h
echo timestamp > localedir.hs
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o lex.o -MT lex.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/lex.Tpo ../.././libcpp/lex.c
mkdir -p -- ../../host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0 /home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc/host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lto-plugin/../../host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc/host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lto-plugin/../../host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc && { ln -s -f liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0 liblto_plugin.so.0 || { rm -f liblto_plugin.so.0 && ln -s liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0 liblto_plugin.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc/host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lto-plugin/../../host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc && { ln -s -f liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0 liblto_plugin.so || { rm -f liblto_plugin.so && ln -s liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0 liblto_plugin.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/liblto_plugin.lai /home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc/host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lto-plugin/../../host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/liblto_plugin.la
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc/host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lto-plugin'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc/host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lto-plugin'
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o line-map.o -MT line-map.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/line-map.Tpo ../.././libcpp/line-map.c
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o macro.o -MT macro.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/macro.Tpo ../.././libcpp/macro.c
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o mkdeps.o -MT mkdeps.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/mkdeps.Tpo ../.././libcpp/mkdeps.c
g++  -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include  -march=armv8-a -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../.././libcpp -I. -I../.././libcpp/../include -I../.././libcpp/include   -c -o pch.o -MT pch.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/pch.Tpo ../.././libcpp/pch.c
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc/host-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/libcpp'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/asi/Balickovac/src/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/gcc'
```

Full make output at https://pastebin.com/KpwyLfWZ
After googling I have read about problems compiling older gcc using a newer version, but as Manjaro's aarch64 is rather fresh, gcc version 10.2.0 is as old as it's available and attempting to compile an older version would have the same result... I don't have another computer (My old toughbook was killed in a rather spectacular manner with its metal frame melted in the process)
and I can't use other peoples computers to the development level. so I can't compile on older and I am not sure about which level chrooting to intell32bit would work on the arm platform.

Any ideas?

Comment: being just a pi4 with 2GB ram, Emulation might be too much for it. Any idea how to compile it?

Comment: There are errors: “error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]”. If you disable the corresponding `-Werror` option they won’t fail the build.